# Can I grab the class of an element onmouseover and use that in a variable?

Tags: javascript, class, variables

I have a simulation created of a musical instrument. It's created using a table. Currently, if I hover over the class="ENat" shown below(which would be a E note) , it highlights all the "ENat" classes (E Notes) on the page. Perfect!

But, what I want it to do, is pass the class I'm hovering over to the 'elms' variable so it works on all the different classes (notes) that I have created without being redundant with the code. So if I hover over an 'A' note class, all 'A' notes change, etc. First post, so forgive me if I wasn't clear enough.

```
var elms = document.getElementsByClassName('ENat');
var n = elms.length;
function changeColor(color) {
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        elms[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    elms[i].onmouseover = function() {
        changeColor("red");
    };
    elms[i].onmouseout = function() {
        changeColor("tan");
    };
}
```

Comment: You need them all different because different notes are going to get different colors? If they are all the same, including the colors, then give them all the same class. If you need a way further to identify separate notes, you could then use a custom attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You want to delegate - I have implemented using a table as you said, but you can have the classes on any element, like span or div:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => { // on page load
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("mouseover", overAndOut)
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("mouseout", overAndOut)
});
const overAndOut = e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (e.target.classList.contains("note")) {
    const className = tgt.className.match(/[A-H]Nat/); // match on note classname
    [...document.querySelectorAll("." + className)]
    .forEach(elem => elem.style.backgroundColor = e.type === "mouseover" ? "red" : "tan");
  }
};
```

```css
.note {
  background-color: tan
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="container">
    <tr>
      <td class="note ANat">A</td>
      <td class="note BNat">B</td>
      <td class="note CNat">C</td>
      <td class="note DNat">D</td>
      <td class="note ENat">E</td>
      <td class="note FNat">F</td>
      <td class="note GNat">G</td>
      <td class="note HNat">H/B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="note ANat">A</td>
      <td class="note BNat">B</td>
      <td class="note CNat">C</td>
      <td class="note DNat">D</td>
      <td class="note ENat">E</td>
      <td class="note FNat">F</td>
      <td class="note GNat">G</td>
      <td class="note HNat">H/B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="note ANat">A</td>
      <td class="note BNat">B</td>
      <td class="note CNat">C</td>
      <td class="note DNat">D</td>
      <td class="note ENat">E</td>
      <td class="note FNat">F</td>
      <td class="note GNat">G</td>
      <td class="note HNat">H/B</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
window.onmouseover=function(e) {
    var elms = document.getElementsByClassName(e.target.className);
    // Change colors
};
```

This should get the class name of the element you're hovering over, which you can then use to highlight all the elements with that class name.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i've understand your question.
You want every note to be highlighted if shares your hover note, right?

In that case, simply call a function when mouseover in every note, not only in "ENat" ones, in every case highlight everything that matches that class.

```js
for(key of document.querySelectorAll('.ANat, .BNat, .ENat')){
    key.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){changeColor(this.classList[0], "red")}, false);
    key.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){changeColor(this.classList[0], "tan")}, false);
}

function changeColor(className, color) {
  for(elem of document.querySelectorAll('div.' + className)){
     elem.style.backgroundColor = color
  }
}
```

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:tan;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="ENat"></div>
<div class="ENat"></div>
<div class="ANat"></div>
<div class="ANat"></div>
<div class="BNat"></div>
<div class="BNat"></div>
<div class="ENat"></div>
<div class="BNat"></div>
```

Comment: I find [delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61618475/295783) more elegant

Comment: Yes, i've upvoted you already XD, this way (mine) seems easier for begginers to me.

Comment: I do not think your code is easier to understand (this.classList[0] is pretty tricky) - if the className changes order, then there could be an issue. I will revisit mine too to make it safer

Comment: I saw it yesterday and thought the same. Have been thinking about using regex and now i see that was you solution too